# Log time and changed sheet for an Audit Trail

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an audit trail in Excel. I want to log the time and the worksheet where the changes have been made.

```
Dim PreviousValue

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
    Sheets("log").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
        Application.UserName & " changed cell " & Target.Address _
        & " from " & PreviousValue & " to " & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is working. The only issue is that you should paste it in the Sheet you want to audit. So if you have "Sheet1" sheet, just right click button on the tab>Show Code. Then paste your code and... done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
    Sheets("log").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
        Application.UserName & " changed cell " & Target.Address _
        & " from " & PreviousValue & " to " & Target.Value & " from sheet " & ActiveSheet.Name & " at " & Time
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target.Value
End Sub
```